# Passing comma seperated list to url in Classic ASP using javascript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I have coma separated list of values in classic ASP from db (ids=(1,2,3,5,6)) which needs to be passed to javascript function to pass to a url.

The javascript function is called from vb script as follows.

```
 <span onclick='showcate(ids)'>gohere</span>
```

js function is as follows.

```
 function showcate(ids)
{
  form1.action=".\abc.asp?aa=<%=xx>&bb="+ids+"&cc=<%=yy%>";
  form1.submit();
 }
```

how can I do this?

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: ids are being passed as [object] to the SQL query, so I get the oracle error.So the url will look like this: abc.asp?aa=12&bb=[object]&cc=34.       Or do I need insert the values in array ,pass the array and in the js function make it coma separated again? is there any way to do directly with coma separated list?

Comment: If `ids` is an Array then just use `ids = Join(ids, ",")` to create a comma delimited string and pass that to avoid the `[object]` issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ASP variable name is ids where you have this comma separated list of values, you can pass them in javascript as:

```
<span onclick='showcate(<%=ids%>)'>gohere</span>
```